# To pass an array into a function

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I have a class called Planet.

And I have an array of Planet objects.

I declared the array as follows:

```
planet * planetList[5] = 
{
  new planet(...),
  new planet(...),
  new planet(...),
  new planet(...),
  new planet(...),
};
```

And so I need to pass this array into these 2 functions.

For both functions, I declare them as such, with exactly the same parameters:

```
void function1 (planet planetList[5], int numOfPlanets) {...}
void function2 (planet planetList[5], int numOfPlanets) {...}
```

But when I call these 2 functions,

```
// receives no error
function1(planetList, numOfPlanets);
// error saying "cannot convert parameter 1 from 'planet *[5]' to 'planet []'"
function2(planetList, numOfPlanets);
```

Can anyone explain this phenomenon?

Comment: You could probably get away with making an array of Planets and then not using new.  That's usually how I do stuff like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've declared an array of planet pointers (planet * []), but the function parameters are planet object arrays (planet []). As such, neither function call should work.

Try:

```
void function1(planet *planetList[5], int numOfPlanets) {}
void function2(planet *planetList[5], int numOfPlanets) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
void function1 (planet** planetList, int numOfPlanets) {...}
void function2 (planet** planetList, int numOfPlanets) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of pointers that points to the object.You have an array of pointers that points to the object  so any pointer to array of pointer will do the wrk for you
for ex
`void function1 (planet *planetList[5], int numOfPlanets) {...}

void function2 (planet *planetList[5], int numOfPlanets) {...}`

or

`void function1 (planet **planetList, int numOfPlanets) {...}

void function2 (planet **planetList, int numOfPlanets) {...}`

Answer (score 0):

> I have an array of Planet objects

No, you have an array of pointers to Planet objects. An array of objects would look like:

```
planet planetList[5] = 
{
  planet(...),
  planet(...),
  planet(...),
  planet(...),
  planet(...),
};
```

That is probably what you want.

If you really want an array of pointer for some reason, then you'll need to change the functions to accept that:

```
void function1(planet * planetList[5], int numOfPlanets);
```

or equivalently

```
void function1(planet ** planetList, int numOfPlanets);
```

> Can anyone explain this phenomenon?

No, both functions should fail to compile in the same way. Could you post a more complete example so we can reproduce the phenomenon ourselves?

Comment: Yes, you were right that both functions do not work as intended. It is however, for one of my function, it shows no compilation errors. The functions work correctly now after implementing your declarations. Thank you.